# ASP.NET Membership database and performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

We're writing a custom admin page for our ASP.NET MVC 3 app and we're surprised by how long it takes to grab users from the aspnet "application services" database.

The built-in Membership.GetAllUsers() method is painfully slow, but understandably so since it fetches a large quantity of info for each user. We don't need that much so we decided to throw a LINQ to SQL layer on top of our aspnet db and write our own queries using LINQ. Instead of fetching everything, we just get a couple columns - the only ones we're interested in.

The results are better, but still: it takes about 30 seconds to fetch a bit more than 120 users with the standard method versus 9 seconds with our custom query.

9 seconds for 150 rows seems huge. Any idea why it takes so long ?

**EDIT** Here's an example of a method that takes 9 seconds to return something:

```
    public static List<LightMembershipUser> GetUsersInRole(string roleName) {
        //Find the role
        var roleId =   (from role in db.Roles
                        where roleName == role.RoleName
                        select role.RoleId)
                        .First();
        if (roleId==null){ return null; }

        var res =   from u in db.Users 
                    join ur in db.UsersInRoles on u.UserId equals ur.UserId
                    join m in db.Memberships on u.UserId equals m.UserId
                    where  ur.RoleId==roleId
                    select new LightMembershipUser { UserName = u.UserName, CreationDate = m.CreateDate, Email = m.Email, Roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName) };
        return res.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Did you measure from a cold start or from an already running app pool?

Comment: Doesn't this bit `Roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName)` mean you are doing 150 queries, like Mystere Man suggested? Have you looked at the SQL produced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing specific to the Membership system that would cause slow access, and your 120 users in 30 seconds is not something that should be typical.  Membership are just a set of tables in the database, they're not even a seperate database unless you set it up that way.  They're just rows.

There is clearly something wrong with your database server.  You should be able to return 150 rows in microseconds, even on a slow server.  You might try including your query in your question though, since maybe it's something you're doing wrong.

Wait.. are you doing 150 queries?  Or one query returning 150 records?  Obviously, the Membership API provides no way to return multiple Users at once, so if you're using Membership you have to do 150 queries to get 150 users.  But your own queries should be able to work on as many rows as you like.

Comment: Figured it out. That `Roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName)` call triggers an individual database query for each record found. So yeah, I'm doing 150 queries in the end. Stupid me.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you don't use aspnet database at all, rather make your own database and your classes that extend `MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider`.

Can you provide your query?